# C++ NetLink Sockets Error

Tags: c++, sockets, netlink

I recently started again on a C++ application. I am using NetLink for Sockets and Visual Studio for developing.

I made a small code but I got some errors. I've included the files from NetLink and I added ws2_32.lib (in linker/general & as pragma comment), but I still got these errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl NL::init(void)" (?init@NL@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main  c:\Users\Joshua\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\OBPP\OBPP\Main.obj
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class NL::Socket * __thiscall NL::Socket::accept(void)" (?accept@Socket@NL@@QAEPAV12@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall OnAccept::exec(class NL::Socket *,class NL::SocketGroup *,void *)" (?exec@OnAccept@@EAEXPAVSocket@NL@@PAVSocketGroup@3@PAX@Z)  c:\Users\Joshua\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\OBPP\OBPP\Main.obj
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall NL::SocketGroup::listen(unsigned int,void *)" (?listen@SocketGroup@NL@@QAE_NIPAX@Z) referenced in function _main c:\Users\Joshua\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\OBPP\OBPP\Main.obj
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall NL::SocketGroup::SocketGroup(void)" (??0SocketGroup@NL@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main  c:\Users\Joshua\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\OBPP\OBPP\Main.obj
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall NL::Socket::Socket(unsigned int,enum NL::Protocol,enum NL::IPVer,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int)" (??0Socket@NL@@QAE@IW4Protocol@1@W4IPVer@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I@Z) referenced in function _main  c:\Users\Joshua\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\OBPP\OBPP\Main.obj
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall NL::Socket::~Socket(void)" (??1Socket@NL@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main    c:\Users\Joshua\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\OBPP\OBPP\Main.obj
Error   7   error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals   c:\users\joshua\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\OBPP\Debug\OBPP.exe
```

Code I'm using (just wanted to try out accepting):

```
#include <iostream>

#include "netlink\socket.h"
#include "netlink\socket_group.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define PORT 30000

class OnAccept: public NL::SocketGroupCmd {
        void exec(NL::Socket* socket, NL::SocketGroup* group, void* reference) {
                NL::Socket* newConnection = socket->accept();
                group->add(newConnection);
            std::cout << "\nConnection " << newConnection->hostTo() << ":" << newConnection->portTo() << " added...";
            std::cout.flush();
    }
};

int main()
{
    NL::init();
    NL::Socket s(PORT);
    NL::SocketGroup group;

    group.setCmdOnAccept(&OnAccept());

    group.add(&s);

    if (group.listen(2000))
    {
            std::cout << "Listening on Sockets, port " << PORT << std::endl;
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you are targeting `x86_64`/win64 and that library has only 32-bit object code.

Comment: No, I'm targeting win32.

Comment: Well I just think it, are you talking about the dropdown next to Debug/Release under the 'menustrip' line? The platform in solution settings is also Win32, and in my project settings it's also Win32.

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of the library. It can't be used with the headers only, you need to link the static/dynamic compiled library.

You have to build the library first, to generate the .lib file. Once you have the netLink.lib file built (or whatever you name it) you have to add that dependency to the linker.

Answer (score 0):

I am not visual studio developer, But error message says `unresolved external symbol` means linker is not able to find some symbols.
  Look at you linking command does it include Netlink library?

Comment: Jep. I don't get any errors in my Main.cpp file (where my entry point is located). The library where all netlink header files are is included.

Comment: i think you will have some dll file for netlink right?

Comment: Nope. I prevent usage of .dll. And it should work by just including the header files to the properties of the project, but it doesn't.

Comment: i dint get you you need library(dll) at runtime to execute routines inside, Unless its specific to visual studio? how do you find routines at runtime to execute your program?

Comment: I'm not using C++/CLI but I'm using Win32 C++ (which doesn't use the .NET Framework). For Win32 C++ you don't need usage of dll's. Mostly you use .lib's or you use path's with header files (in my case)

Comment: first line says its not able to resolve `NL::init(void)` method os NetLink lib. So init method is external symbol to you program(entry point), And has to be located in some dll like NetLink.dll....

Comment: is .lib means static library?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It still gives the error if I include the header files in my own project.

Comment: define those symbols as `extern`, So it wont look at link time, But will require at runtime only..For example `extern NL::init();`

Comment: For more precise info have a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx).

Comment: No... void init(); nothing's external in my project.

Comment: you can always check dependencies by `dependecywalker`

Comment: No `void init()` but `NL::init();`